# JAVA - getting Random from different class

Tags: java, random, jframe, jpanel, draw

Hey I have got an application that generates random shapes in random locations and now I'm trying to divide the code into classes responsible for certain things. But when I cut out part of the code responsible for "randomizing" and moved it to another class, it's not working (not randomizing) anymore. Any ideas? My code below:

MAIN CLASS

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new TestPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestPanel();
    Main frame = new Main();
    frame.setSize(1000, 700);
    frame.setTitle("Random things");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //frame.setResizable(false);
}

}
```

TESTPANEL CLASS

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel {
    Randoms randomized = new Randoms();
    int howManyGeometrics = randomized.random1.nextInt(5-1) + 1;
    int whichGeometrics = randomized.random1.nextInt(3);

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < howManyGeometrics; i++) {
            draw(g);
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        if(whichGeometrics==0){
            //oval
            g.setColor(randomized.randomColour2);
            g.fillOval(randomized.x1, randomized.x2, randomized.x4, randomized.x3);

            //triangle
            g.setColor(randomized.randomColour3);
            int xpoints[] = {randomized.x1+10, randomized.x2+15, randomized.x3+20};
            int ypoints[] = {randomized.x4-20, randomized.x3-15, randomized.x2-20};
            int npoints = 3;
            g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, npoints);

            //hourglass
            g.setColor(randomized.randomColour4);
            int a1=50+randomized.x1;
            int a2=200+randomized.x2;
            int a3=a1;
            int a4=a2;
            int b1=a1;
            int b2=a2/2;
            int b3=a2/2;
            int b4=a1;
            int x1points[] = {a1, a2, a3, a4};
            int y1points[] = {b1, b2, b3, b4};
            int ntpoints = 4;
            g.fillPolygon(x1points, y1points, ntpoints);
        }

        else if(whichGeometrics==1){
            //rectangle
            g.setColor(randomized.randomColour1);
            g.fillRect(randomized.x2, randomized.x3, randomized.x1, randomized.x4/2);

            //triangle
            g.setColor(randomized.randomColour3);
            int xpoints[] = {randomized.x1+10, randomized.x2+15, randomized.x3+20};
            int ypoints[] = {randomized.x4-20, randomized.x3-15, randomized.x2-20};
            int npoints = 3;
            g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, npoints);

            //hourglass
            g.setColor(randomized.randomColour4);

            int a1=50+randomized.x1;
            int a2=200+randomized.x2;
            int a3=a1;
            int a4=a2;
            int b1=a1;
            int b2=a2/2;
            int b3=a2/2;
            int b4=a1;
            int x1points[] = {a1, a2, a3, a4};
            int y1points[] = {b1, b2, b3, b4};
            int ntpoints = 4;
            g.fillPolygon(x1points, y1points, ntpoints);
            }

        else if(whichGeometrics==2){
            //rectangle
            g.setColor(randomized.randomColour1);
            g.fillRect(randomized.x2, randomized.x3, randomized.x1, randomized.x4/2);

            //oval
            g.setColor(randomized.randomColour2);
            g.fillOval(randomized.x1, randomized.x2, randomized.x4, randomized.x3);

            //hourglass
            g.setColor(randomized.randomColour4);

            int a1=50+randomized.x1;
            int a2=200+randomized.x2;
            int a3=a1;
            int a4=a2;
            int b1=a1;
            int b2=a2/2;
            int b3=a2/2;
            int b4=a1;
            int x1points[] = {a1, a2, a3, a4};
            int y1points[] = {b1, b2, b3, b4};
            int ntpoints = 4;
            g.fillPolygon(x1points, y1points, ntpoints);
            }

        else if(whichGeometrics==3){
            //rectangle
            g.setColor(randomized.randomColour1);
            g.fillRect(randomized.x2, randomized.x3, randomized.x1, randomized.x4/2);

            //oval
            g.setColor(randomized.randomColour2);
            g.fillOval(randomized.x1, randomized.x2, randomized.x4, randomized.x3);

            //triangle
            g.setColor(randomized.randomColour3);
            int xpoints[] = {randomized.x1+10, randomized.x2+15, randomized.x3+20};
            int ypoints[] = {randomized.x4-20, randomized.x3-15, randomized.x2-20};
            int npoints = 3;
            g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, npoints);
            }
    }
}
```

RANDOMS CLASS

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

public class Randoms {

    Random random1 = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    int x1 = random1.nextInt(800);
    int x2 = random1.nextInt(800);
    int x3 = random1.nextInt(800);
    int x4 = random1.nextInt(800);

    int red = random1.nextInt(255);
    int green = random1.nextInt(255);
    int blue = random1.nextInt(255);

    Color randomColour1 = new Color(red,green,blue);
    Color randomColour2 = new Color(green,blue,red);
    Color randomColour3 = new Color(blue,red,green);
    Color randomColour4 = new Color(green,red,red,green);
}
```

I will be grateful for help or/and advices :)

Comment: First, how do you know it's not randomizing? Second, `int red = random1.nextInt(255)` will produce values between 0 and 254.  You need int `red = random1.nextInt(256)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John3136 already pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21639680 , the main problem is that you are always using the same `Randoms` instance. But admittedly, this `Randoms` class itself seems questionable in its current form. The random values are stored as *fields* implicitly causing the original issue. I could imagine that such a `Randoms` class might be more useful if it contained the appropriate *methods*. For example, methods like

```
class Randoms 
{
    private static final Random random = 
        new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public static Color createRandomColor()
    {
        int red = random.nextInt(255);
        int green = random.nextInt(255);
        int blue = random.nextInt(255);
        return new Color(red,green,blue);
    }

    public static int nextInt(int min, int max)
    {
        return random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
    }
}
```

Apart from that: The code for the "hourglass" is always the same. In such cases, you should consider creating a method like

```
private void paintHourglass(Graphics g, int x0, int x1) { 
    // Here the repeated code...
}
```

Maybe you should more clearly describe what you want to achieve. If you just want to generate a set of random shapes, then you can create them and store them in a list:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RandomsTest extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TestPanel());
        frame.setSize(1000, 700);
        frame.setTitle("Random things");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //frame.setResizable(false);
    }

}

class TestPanel extends JPanel
{
    private List<Geometry> geometries;

    TestPanel()
    {
        geometries = new ArrayList<Geometry>();
        int numGeometries = Randoms.nextInt(5, 8);
        for (int i=0; i<numGeometries; i++)
        {
            geometries.add(new Geometry());
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
        for (Geometry geometry : geometries)
        {
            geometry.draw(g);
        }
    }
}




class Geometry
{
    private final Color color;
    private final Shape shape;

    Geometry()
    {
        this.color = Randoms.createRandomColor();
        this.shape = Shapes.createRandomShape();
    }

    void draw(Graphics2D g)
    {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fill(shape);
    }

}

class Shapes
{
    static Shape createRandomShape()
    {
        int type = Randoms.nextInt(2);
        switch (type)
        {
            case 0 : return createRandomOval();
            case 1 : return createRandomRectangle();
        }
        return createRandomOval();
    }

    private static Shape createRandomOval()
    {
        return new Ellipse2D.Double(
            Randoms.nextInt(800),
            Randoms.nextInt(800),
            Randoms.nextInt(800),
            Randoms.nextInt(800));
    }

    private static Shape createRandomRectangle()
    {
        return new Rectangle2D.Double(
            Randoms.nextInt(800),
            Randoms.nextInt(800),
            Randoms.nextInt(800),
            Randoms.nextInt(800));
    }
}

class Randoms
{
    private static final Random random =
        new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public static Color createRandomColor()
    {
        int red = random.nextInt(255);
        int green = random.nextInt(255);
        int blue = random.nextInt(255);
        return new Color(red,green,blue);
    }

    public static int nextInt(int min, int max)
    {
        return random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
    }

    public static int nextInt(int max)
    {
        return random.nextInt(max);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to have random number of randomly generated shapes everytime I restart my application.

Comment: That is what the example application does. Of course, you can extend it with further random Shapes in the `Shapes` class (e.g. the hourglass, or completely random shapes using Path2D)

Comment: Yay thanks man, now I did understand it, but I need one more thing and I have no idea how to make that happend - is there any way to have another random geometrics after resizing JFrame (I mean after I start application)?

Comment: Describe more clearly what you mean. Should the geometries change every time that you *resize* the frame, or every time that the frame is *repainted*? In doubt, just move the creation of the geometries in the TestPanel from the constructor into paintComponent....

Comment: Yes, It should change every time I resize the frame :)

Comment: Take the code from the constructor of PaintPanel, and put this code into the paintComponent method. This is ugly as hell and does not make sense, but if you want it, you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You create one instance of `Randoms` and then keep using it's members `x1` etc without changing their value.

I suspect your old working code created multiple `Randoms` instances?

A simple solution would be to add a `reRandomize()` method to `Randoms` that sets each member to a new random value and call that before each shape.

Comment: Nope, I had only one Random instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Math.random() every time you need a new random number.

Comment: In general, I recommend to NOT use Math.random(). The problem with Math.random() is that it is hard to debug: You never can achieve the same sequence of random numbers. With `java.util.Random` this can easily be achieved by creating the `new Random(seed)` instance with a fixed seed value. Additionally, `java.util.Random` contains conventient methods like `nextInt`, that you have to implement yourself when using Math.random()

Comment: @Marco13 If you can never achieve the same sequence of random numbers, then it's random. Otherwise it would be pseudo-random.

Comment: All numbers returned by java.util.Random or Math.random are pseudo-random. The crucial point is that in the first case, you can define the random seed (and thus, obtain always the same sequence of numbers), and in the lattern, you can't.